# Determine return type based on object property

Tags: typescript

I have the following TypeScript code:

```js
const elements = [
    { key: 1, value: 'foo' },
    { key: 2, value: 'bar' }
] as const;

type MyElement = typeof elements[number];

function getElementValue(key: MyElement['key']): MyElement['value'] | undefined {
    const element = elements.find(element => element.key === key);
    if (element) {
        return element.value;
    }
    return undefined;
}

const x = getElementValue(1);
//    ^? const x: "foo" | "bar" | undefined

const y = getElementValue(2);
//    ^? const y: "foo" | "bar" | undefined

const z = getElementValue(3); //  correct compile error
```

This already ensures that only valid `keys` can be inserted into the function.
However, currently, the correct return type cannot be fully determined at compile time.

Is there a way to make sure that TypeScript knows that `getElementValue(1)` always returns `foo`
and `getElementValue(2)` always returns `bar`?

Here is the corresponding [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgGzgWzmKEYF4YG0CwAUDCTAN4wDWcAngFwwCMANDAG4CGCArnAwOQAzECH4wAvsyKlyVWgwBMrTjz4x%20AIw4AnMeKIBdGB0yhIUANxEiUGgAc4MALI0AoklTpsMWw5CD4DzQMXDBuZA04bQMrQiJBbjBgKABLcBgAczgodxRggDUuXgAKanpnNyD0XH4y-gMASgYXXM8oGpVeepgAHxhEgBM4QRSwOAHyaVIzaEC8rxxEeYwAOhGwAeKltuwAPjm2lbLsLBwyhtiZFICtqqgGyeIZUm1s7m0wA%20CVzrhL0n0TxIryg70%20g2Go3GsUBRBmsAAHt4sjk7oVVMVGBciAB6HEyAB6AH5rIR4TAaMjsq0CkU4MUFNjCHjCSS4mTwLMAF5U1HLdElADMFxgLJgoG0r2S4pAyDsKSQ8ElIG0QA).

Comment: Make the function generic with respect to the `key` parameter: https://tsplay.dev/NdvVkW

Comment: What if there are multiple objects with the same `key` value? A [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) is probably a more suitable structure in this case than an array.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76074595/determine-return-type-based-on-object-property#comment134166184_76074595) For example: this probably misuses a not-guaranteed behavior of TypeScript's resolution for intersection merging, but it works in the playground: https://tsplay.dev/NrQV0w